# How to download software for Red Hat Linux without registering in Red Hat Network

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm new to Linux and I'm now using RHEL 6. When I'm trying to download software they force me to register on the Red Hat Network.

Is there any other process to download software for RHEL without that?

Comment: If you have RHEL, why don't you have a Red Hat Network login? Or why couldn't you create one?

Comment: I am very confused by your question. Are you familiar with yum, the package manager to install packages?

Comment: @JaredBurrows AFAIK, `yum` relies on the RHN to make updates: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.3/html/Reference_Guide/ch-register.html

Comment: Mosty likely, however you can setup different repositories:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel6-beta-howto-use-yum-command-to-install-packages-without-rhn/

Comment: it needs money to register in RHN and i'm looking for free access

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer your question directly but it may be a good solution. Switch to CentOS. It is a direct clone of Red Hat. Check this link out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS

I've been using CentOS for many years and love it.